# Twilio Say Verb during a phone call

Tags: php, xml, twilio

Based off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863305/twilio-say-verb-nested-into-a-dial-verb), it's so close to what I want.

We're trying to have the Say verb trigger DURING the phone call, when both parties have established connections. Not before pickup, not after hangup, not during client ringing.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+[some number]" record="true">
        <Number url="say.php">
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["tocall"]); ?>
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

And say.php..

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="man" language="en">Long sentence to test quality of call over duration of [time]</Say>
</Response>
```

As you can see, we're doing this to test the quality of a call over the duration of 2 hours, so ignore what it's actually "say"ing.

What do I have to do to make this say verb trigger during a connected phone call, and not any of the pre/post stage call process?

Comment: Have you tried multiple Say verbs separated by Pause verb? Is it just a specific amount of time you want it to wait before proceeding?

Comment: @codenheim it's more on the connection -- we have all the content to fill the time, but my issue is that the say verb triggers before both parties are connected, not during the actual call.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. There is a solution for that specific scenario, but I can't recall so I need to refer back to the Twilio docs.

Comment: I must have been thinking about the Gather command, combined with Say. You can also use Pause, but that isn't flexible enough. If you use Gather you can wait until someone presses a key before continuing. That doesn't really sound like what you are looking for though, but that`s all I see with the current TwiML API.

Comment: Twilio dev here.This is a multi-step process: 1) Connect the call between person A and person B as you have already done. Make sure to specify a [status callback URL](https://https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) that points to your webapp. 2) When Twilio calls this URL and passes the status of  [in-progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status) you know the call is live. 3) Now use the REST API to [modify the live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#example-1) and inject your TwiML.

Comment: @CarterRabasa this is awesome, thank you for those links!

Comment: Could you put that as an answer? This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Will do. I thought the etiquette was to comment and then that comment could be promoted to an answer by the OP?

Comment: @CarterRabasa nope, if the comment answers the question, by all means just post it as an answer. No comment needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio employee here. This is a multi-step process:

1) Connect the call between person A and person B as you have already done. Make sure to specify a [status callback URL](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) that points to your webapp.

2) When Twilio calls this URL and passes the status of [in-progress](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status) you know the call is live.

3) Now use the REST API to [modify the live call](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#example-1) and inject your TwiML.

That should do it.

Comment: As a "Twilio Employee", please provide an example...the page you mention do show how to "inject a twiml" ...i also need to play a message on an ongoing call...like " you are now the number 2 in line to be connected"

Comment: It seems like modifying the live call ends the call (dial), any idea on how to get around that issue?